# Multiplicity constraint violated. The role Child_Parent_Target of the relationship Child_Parent has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-6

I did a lot of research but haven't found any answer that matches my problem. I even tried to use the *[The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro)* example. No success.

I'm working with Entity Framework 6 Code First (Fluent API), POCO Classes.

I have a class called Parent and a class called Child

One Parent can have one or more Childs (one to many relationship)

So, in my ParentMapping class I did:

```
HasMany(p => p.Childs).WithRequired(p => p.Parent).Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentId"));
```

and in my ChildMapping class I did:

```
HasRequired(p => p.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Childs).Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentId"));
```

I persist (Insert, Update and Delete) my child poco class at the same time I persist the parent class. So every time I save my parent class, it has one or more child objects in its *Childs* property. Thus the parent object is responsible for persist its child objects.

I followed the example above (see the link) to save data into the database.

I get below message when I try to add a new child to the db existent Parent, which already has one child in the database, and call the *db.SaveChanges*:

**Multiplicity constraint violated. The role Child_Parent_Target of the relationship Child_Parent has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.**

Can anyone help me? I'm struggling with this and see no light in the end of the tunnel.

Comment: You really should show the code where this exception is raised.

Comment: @GertArnold I thank you for your comment. But I think I've explained everything clearly. Btw, I've answered the question and I really suggest you check it out. It's very instructive, from my point of view. Anyway, thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using GraphDiff amazing library. It just does everything for us when talking about parent/child persisting.

Check it out at this post: [GraphDiff - Allowing automated updates of a graph of detached entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/13820802#13820802)